# catch exceptions from another process

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

I would like to know the possibility of catching exceptions and their relevant stack traces that might occur in any process or thread within a process. Is it even possible (say in Linux)? Please have a look at an example of what I am trying to do:

- OS : Linux
- P1 : Java Process (Running some app inside it)
- P2 : Python Process
- P3 : C++ process
- P4 : My custom monitoring code (listening to exceptions that might happen in P1, P2, P3)

Lets say P1 generates an exception that happens in it code (say NullPointerException) which is caught correctly in the Java code and relevant exception handling procedure runs. Similarly, exceptions might happen in P2 and P3 later in time.

Can P4 (another process only listening for exceptions in P1, P2 and P3) capture all handled/unhandled exceptions in P1, P2, P3? Is it even possible in Linux? If yes, what would be required to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

In Linux OS you can use the interface which is primary build in for debugging. Look for system call *ptrace*.

from *man ptrace*

> The  ptrace() system call provides a means by which one process (the "tracer") may observe and control the execution of another process (the "tracee"), and examine
>   and change the tracee's memory and registers.  It is primarily used to implement breakpoint debugging and system call tracing.

If you want to know how to get internal information's from the processes you are tracing, you should start with the gdb sources. Maybe have a look in gdb/linux-nat.c as a start point.

But this gives you the OS view on the things you are running. A python script itself is not running and traceable. Instead the python interpreter can be traced. But the information you can get from your os will not provide any useful information from the python language itself. Debugging a python script or a java byte code program is very special. You have to connect to the debug interface of the interpreter if available. For python you can get a debugger pdb. Maybe you can start to inspect this sources how to debug a python program.

Good luck :-)

Answer (score -2):

A practical, straight-forward way of achieving this:

Log all errors from P1-3 into logfiles.

Watch these logfiles with P4.